# How do i repeat my table / RadListView x times?

Tags: asp.net, html, telerik

I have made one html-table that contain a RadListView (with use of LayoutTemplate and ItemTemplate), and it works fine.

It's a Property-table with two columns ("CadastralNummer", "CadastralSomething").
(The table has as many rows as the property has cadastrals)

Now comes the tricky part for me!

I now have a list of properties, instead of just one. 
How do repeat my table for every property below each other?

If it can help, here's my code for one table:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0" width="75%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <td style="width: 25%;">
          CadastralNummer
        </td>
        <td style="width: 25%;">
        CadastralSomething
        </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <telerik:RadListView runat="server" 
        ID="RadListViewProperty"     
        AllowPaging="false" DataKeyNames="PropertyNR" 
        OverrideDataSourceControlSorting="true"
        ItemPlaceholderID="ListViewContainer" 
        OnItemDataBound="RadListViewProperty_ItemDataBound">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="listViewContainer" />
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: top;">
        <asp:Label ID="lblCadastralNummer" runat="server" />
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align: top;">
        <asp:Label ID="lblCadastralSomething" runat="server" />
        </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </telerik:RadListView>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put my table/RadListView inside another table/RadListView, and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the [repeater control](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/asp-net-repeater-control)?  This may provide what you need.